# Why are my messages not sending to the Socket.io room with this handler?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

The way of sending a message to a specific room [in Socket.io according to the docs](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#rooms) seems really simple. In the following code is a handler, part of a bigger module, but the functionality should all be straightforward, especially since I'm showing the logs which expose what each variable represents:

```
module.exports.handle = function(client, data, socket, sessions, callback) {
    debug.log('Client, ' + data.name + ' sent message:' + data.message);
    debug.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 3));
    var sessionId = data.code;
    var name = data.name;
    var room = JSON.stringify(socket.sockets.adapter.rooms[sessionId]);
    debug.log('Socket.io Room: ' + room);
    socket.to(sessionId).emit('receive message', {
        name : data.name,
        message : data.message,
        sender : client.id
    });
};
```

Its appears clear in the following logs (based on the previous code) that the room I specify is a valid Socket.io room, so I dont understand why (in this instance) `.to('M57VUYD1')` is failing to send the message to the room. The logs seem to verify that `M57VUYD1` in this case is a valid room.

```
[Debug][Send Message Event Handler]: Client, Jonathan sent message:hey
[Debug][Send Message Event Handler]: {
   "message": "hey",
   "name": "Jonathan",
   "code": "M57VUYD1"
}
[Debug][Send Message Event Handler]: Socket.io Room: {"sockets":{"57VUYD1":true,"D4N178C":true},"length":2}
```

Is there something wrong with this module for it to not work as expected? Or have I used the correct syntax?

*I was sending these messages globally (non room based) and the client was receiving the messages perfectly*, so I don't think its a problem with my client side socket event listeners. And it doesn't seem to be my module for joining the room, because the logs show two clients being members of the room as they should be in the Socket.io's room data structure.

I added this problem in more detail on GitHub: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2518

Comment: So that no one is confused by the similarity of the room name `M57VUYD1` and the socket ID `57VUYD1`, I'll explain: 57VUYD1 is the ID I defined for the user who happens to have created the room, and I named the room with the creator's ID, except with the letter 'M' prepended (because you cant name a room with the very same ID as a person, because Socket.io's default method of messaging a specific user works by having all users join a new room with their own name, and you use the syntax of sending the message to that room with the `.to()` method.)

Comment: Also to clarify a potential confusion due to variable name preference:  `socket` is what I notice other people name "io" and `client` is what other people call "socket". This is why even in solo projects I should name things according to the standard format. Id go in and change it around to fix that now, but I dont want to mess up any answers currently being written.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is this: Changing the socket IDs in Socket.io, as I learned on Stack Overflow, is something you can do, but what I had not realized is that **doing so will break Socket.io in unknown ways**. One of those ways is: The room system will no longer work.

In other words, dont change the socket IDs to ones of your own choosing, doing so isnt supported by the library.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said, including all of the renaming (which makes it a bit harder to guess), it seems that you have 2 connections: `57VUYD1` which appears to be the server, and `D4N178C` which I'm guessing is the client.  So trying to connect to `M57VUYD1` won't do much.

Try sending to the client's address instead:

```
socket.to('D4N178C').emit('receive message', {
    name : data.name,
    message : data.message,
    sender : client.id
});
```

It may be `57VUYD1` instead of `D4N178C`, as I'm not sure how you've defined things.

I'm also not sure what variable you have assigned that would let you get `D4N178C`, but you can just replace it with whatever works in the `.to()` above and should work.

Comment: You lost me. Why is there a client and server in a list of room members in Socket.io? Theyre all clients... The server is the code you're looking at. Maybe I misunderstood you..

Comment: When a client establishes a socket.io connection Socket.io gives them a unique ID. You can change this ID to your own unique ID of choice. When the client chooses to create a session, a socket.io room is created with the name. In my app, the name is the creator's socket ID with an 'M' prepended. We can check whether a room exists by observing the `io.sockets.adapter.rooms` object. I did this, and it shows the IDs of the two connected clients: D4N178C and 57VUYD1 in that room. But using the `.to()` method on that room isnt doing anything.

Comment: Now, each client connected to the socket, by default in socket.io is put in a room named with his unique ID so one can use the `.to()` method to message that user just like you would message a room. It is a room, it just has one occupant. So if I were to do as you say, it would send the message to one of the rooms two occupants depending on whos ID I specify, not all occupants in the room named .`M57VUYD1` as desired.